# Exporting Google Sheet as PDF with Custom Headers or Footers in Google Apps Script

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

I'm wondering how to add custom headers or footers to a PDF that is exported using Google Apps Script from a Google Sheet. I would like to add a footer that says "My Company Proprietary and Confidential" in the center of the page.

This is functionality that is available in normal PDF export from Sheets (i.e. File » Download as » PDF » Headers & footers » EDIT CUSTOM FIELDS), but I don't know how to replicate it with URL parameters. I've also tried setting `'&sheetnames=true&printtitle=true'`, but this puts the sheet name and spreadsheet name in the header instead of the footer.

Are there any additional URL parameters I can use to control these custom fields?

```
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+sourceSpreadSheet.getId()
  +'/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=letter'                           // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=false'                     // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'                        // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenum=CENTER&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid='+sourceSheet.getSheetId()    // the sheet's Id
  + '&top_margin=0.45&left_margin=0.25&right_margin=0.25&bottom_margin=0.5'; // margins
```

Target Footer:

[image: footer screenshot]

Comment: I've not seen that option: these are the ones I've found so far: https://gist.github.com/andrewroberts/c37d45619d5661cab078be2a3f2fd2bb

Answer (score 0):

I think the workaround would be:

1. create a new document
2. Insert your header
3. Copy the contents of your spreadsheet
4. Insert your footer
5. Export the new file as PDF
6. Trash the new file

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for directly achieving your goal. But, I thought that as a workaround, when the header and footer are added to the exported PDF, your goal might be able to be achieved. In this answer, I would like to propose this workaround. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Export Spreadsheet as PDF.
2. Add the header and footer to the exported PDF.

In order to achieve this, [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) is used. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
/**
 * ### Description
 * Insert header and/or footer into PDF blob.
 *
 * @param {Object} pdfBlob Blob of PDF data for embedding objects.
 * @param {Object} object Object including the values for inserting header and footer.
 * @return {promise} PDF Blob.
 */
async function insertHeaderFooter_(pdfBlob, object) {
  const cdnUrl = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnUrl).getContentText().replace(/setTimeout\(.*?,.*?(\d*?)\)/g, "Utilities.sleep($1);return t();"));
  if (!object || typeof object != "object") {
    throw new Error("Please an object for embeddig the objects.");
  }
  const { header, footer } = object;
  const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
  const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
  const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(new Uint8Array(pdfBlob.getBytes()));
  const numberOfPages = pdfData.getPageCount();
  const pages = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [...Array(numberOfPages)].map((_, i) => i));
  const headers = header ? Object.entries(header).map(([k, v]) => [`header.${k}`, v]) : [];
  const footers = footer ? Object.entries(footer).map(([k, v]) => [`footer.${k}`, v]) : [];
  const sortOrder = ["LEFT", "CENTER", "RIGHT"];
  [footers, headers].forEach((f, _, x) => f.sort((a, b) => {
    const i1 = sortOrder.findIndex(e => a[0].includes(e.toLowerCase()));
    const i2 = sortOrder.findIndex(e => b[0].includes(e.toLowerCase()));
    const vlen = x.length;
    return (i1 > -1 ? i1 : vlen) - (i2 > -1 ? i2 : vlen);
  }));
  const alignObj = { "center": "Center", "left": "Left", "right": "Right" };
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
    const pageNumber = i + 1;
    const page = pdfDoc.addPage(pages[i]);
    const pageHeight = page.getHeight();
    const pageWidth = page.getWidth();
    if (headers.length > 0) {
      const sizeWidthHead = pageWidth / (headers.length);
      for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        const [k, v] = headers[j];
        const o = {
          borderWidth: v.borderWidth || 0,
          x: j * sizeWidthHead,
          y: pageHeight - ((v.yOffset || 0) + (v.height || 20)),
          width: sizeWidthHead,
          height: v.height || 30,
          ...v,
        };
        addHeaderFooterFields_({ page, form, pageNumber, k, v, o, alignObj });
      }
    }
    if (footers.length > 0) {
      const sizeWidthFoot = pageWidth / (footers.length);
      for (let j = 0; j < footers.length; j++) {
        const [k, v] = footers[j];
        const o = {
          borderWidth: v.borderWidth || 0,
          x: j * sizeWidthFoot,
          y: v.yOffset || 0,
          width: sizeWidthFoot,
          height: v.height || 30,
          ...v,
        };
        addHeaderFooterFields_({ page, form, pageNumber, k, v, o, alignObj });
      }
    }
  }
  const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();
  return Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, `new_${pdfBlob.getName()}`);
}

function addHeaderFooterFields_(object) {
  const { page, form, pageNumber, k, v, o, alignObj } = object;
  const fieldName = `${k}.${pageNumber}`;
  const textBox = form.createTextField(fieldName);
  if (v.text) {
    textBox.setText(v.text);
  }
  if (v.alignment) {
    textBox.setAlignment(PDFLib.TextAlignment[alignObj[v.alignment.toLowerCase()]]);
  }
  textBox.disableScrolling();
  textBox.disableMultiline();
  textBox.enableReadOnly();
  ["x", "y", "width", "text"].forEach(e => delete v[e]);
  textBox.addToPage(page, o);
}

// Please run this function.
function myFunction() {
  const object = {
    header: {
      left: { height: 20, alignment: "Center", text: "sample text h1" },
      center: { height: 20, alignment: "Center", text: "sample text h2" },
      right: { height: 20, alignment: "Center", text: "sample text h3" },
    },
    footer: {
      left: { height: 20, alignment: "Center", text: "sample text f1" },
      center: { height: 20, alignment: "Center", text: "sample text f2" },
      right: { height: 20, alignment: "Center", text: "sample text f3" },
    },
  }

  const sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // --- The below script is from your showing script.
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + sourceSpreadSheet.getId()
    + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    + '&size=letter'                           // paper size legal / letter / A4
    + '&portrait=false'                     // orientation, false for landscape
    + '&fitw=true'                        // fit to page width, false for actual size
    + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    + '&pagenum=CENTER&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    + '&gid=' + sourceSheet.getSheetId()    // the sheet's Id
    + '&top_margin=0.45&left_margin=0.25&right_margin=0.25&bottom_margin=0.5'; // margins
  // ---

  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();
  insertHeaderFooter_(blob, object)
    .then(blob => DriveApp.createFile(blob))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following PDF is created in the root folder. You can see the header and footer.

[image]

For example, when you want to add only footer, please use the following `object`.

```js
const object = {
  footer: {
    left: { height: 20, alignment: "Center", text: "sample text f1" },
    center: { height: 20, alignment: "Center", text: "sample text f2" },
    right: { height: 20, alignment: "Center", text: "sample text f3" },
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the pdf-lib library is loaded in the script. But, of course, in this case, you can also use the pdf-lib library by copying and pasting the script library retrieved from `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js` in the script editor of Google Apps Script. In this case, the process cost for loading it can be reduced.

#### References:

- [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/)
- [Add Header and Footer to Exported PDF from Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://medium.com/@tanaike/add-header-and-footer-to-exported-pdf-from-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script-664fe5b190be)