# What is the query parameter used by Google for setting custom headers in the exported pdf?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, export, query-string

Using Google Sheets and working on a script to make exporting (downloading) a PDF copy of a single sheet much easier.  The end goal is to emulate the Download as... PDF, but click of a button and it's done, without having to go to the menu.  Also uses a custom file name (which includes the date and time).

The question...

When exporting a sheet using a script, is there a way to customize the content of the headers?  I know when doing it manually, I can customize what appears in the headers and footers, but what about a script to change the top (or bottom) left/center/right areas when exporting a PDF via script?  I know I can optionally enable a title (printtitle=true) or sheet name (sheetnames=true), but I can't find anything to permit me to customize what appears.

What I would like is to have a custom name/string for the top left and top center, then the date and time in the top right.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that there are no methods for setting the custom headers and footers when the Spreadsheet is exported as a PDF file. Also at this thread, the same situation has already been asked. But no answers are posted yet. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50025746/7108653

Comment: That is unfortunate to hear, but at least I now know that my attempts to find the solution on my own weren't from a lack of proper searches.

Thank you for the response and information.