# Where can I find a list of options for G sheet export to pdf?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing Google Apps script to export a G sheet to pdf, using [this article](http://www.andrewroberts.net/2017/03/apps-script-create-pdf-multi-sheet-google-sheet/) as a basis.

In the list of options that get sent to the spreadsheet export service is "printtitle=true". If I use this then I get the **spreadsheet name** at the top of each page.

I would like to change that name, on the **exported pdf**, so that it includes the date, for example. I'm looking for some documentation on this but can't find it!
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate PDF of only one sheet of my spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197358/generate-pdf-of-only-one-sheet-of-my-spreadsheet)

Comment: You cannot change that option. What you could try is to change the name before exporting and then change it back. Will this work for you?

Comment: I have managed this before (but code now lost!). I wonder if I can specify a header field?

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround:  in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50025746/exporting-google-sheet-as-pdf-with-custom-headers-or-footers-in-google-apps-scri), the author found that you can use 
`&sheetnames=true` which will print the sheet name on the page. So you could change the sheet name "on the fly" to get a kind of customised header.